# How to embed ${ text } into a XSLT

Tags: xslt

Thank you for taking the time to look at my post.

I have an input tag that i need to have output-ed like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_redirect" value="http://www.webpage.com?var1=${root/option1}&amp;var2=${root/option2}" />
```

but i cant get that into my xslt document without it eventually rendering to

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_redirect" value="http://www.webpage.com?var1=$&var2=$" />
```

What do i put in the XSLT to allow me to get that value tag to output like i need it to?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a most easy and staightforward solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just use**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_redirect"
 value="http://www.webpage.com?var1=${{root/option1}}&amp;var2=${{root/option2}}" />
```

**Do note that if we want to output a `'{'` or a `'}'` in an attribute, we have to double them**.

This is because these two characters have special meaning when used inside an attribute: they indicate the start and end of an AVT (attribute-value-template).

Comment: That was it- just doubling the brackets. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the parts:

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_redirect" 
  value="{concat('http://www.webpage.com?var1=${','root/option1}','&amp;var2=${','root/option2}')}" />
```